# Merging 2 clearcase views on different Servers?

Tags: merge, clearcase

I'm in a bit of a pickle...
I work on a project that is multi-site.  Unfortunately, the VOB sync between the two sites is not working properly right now, and our Clearcase Admins are too busy doing other work to get it fixed.

I need to take code from a Dynamic View on one server and merge it to a Dynamic View on another server.

Usually we check everything in, label it, and then once the VOB syncs merge from the label on the other side.

Any tips or tricks on how to do this merge?

---

Ok, here's what I've got so far:
- I made sure that my source view & my target view were based on the same (slightly older) label that had synced properly.

Running the following command tells me what files have changed in my branch on the 1st server:

```
ct find . -version 'version (.../branch-name/LATEST)' -nxn -print
```

Running this command will give me a GNU style diff against the labeled version:

```
ct diff -diff FILENAME `cleartool find FILENAME -version 'lbtype(LABEL)' -print`
```

Now I need to chain these together to create a Patchset file than I can then use GNU Merge to merge into the 2nd view that's based on the same label.

Comment: Ok, so technically now that I think about it is I want to merge data from one VOB based on a label with a VIEW on a Viewserver not connected to that VOB server.

Comment: Your qn. is unclear to me. How are you going to take the code from dynamic view ? It seems to me what you are trying is : make copy of data from dynamic view at one site, copy it to other site, and do the merge at other site with copied data as one of the merge candidate ? Is that your intention ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admins finally got around to cleaning it up before I could finish my solution, so don't need this anymore.  Hopefully they will keep it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data back somehow from the other site of the [replicated environment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/rtnv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.rcc/rcc/7.0/Operations/RCC_CreatingAReplicatedEnvironment/player.html).

if the `mkreplica` did work, but the ship process failed, you could try to ask for a shared file replica, which could then be imported (see [mkreplica help, section Imports](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_ref.doc/topics/mt_mkreplica.htm)).

```
multitool mkreplica –export –workdir /tmp/ms_workdir –c "make a new replica for sanfran_hub" –out /tmp/sanfran_hub_packet 

multitool mkreplica –import –workdir /tmp/ms_workdir –tag /vobs/dev –vob /net/goldengate/vobstg/dev.vbs –preserve –c "create sanfran_hub replica" /tmp/sanfran_hub_packet
```

But if your CC admins are that busy, all there is left is the "replica of the poor":
some kind of zip, and a merge with a third party tool between your local view and said zip.
I am sure you could extract any relevant data from a source dynamic view which would not be up-to-date anyway.